# Create floats from a tuple of bytes

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a blob of data from an SQLite database and convert the blobs contents to a list of floats:

```
import sqlite3
import struct    
conn = sqlite3.connect('my_database.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('select my_column from my_table where time between \'2018-11-15 14:03:04\' and \'2018-11-15 14:03:08\'')

blob_of_data = c.fetchone()
```

At his stage I have a tuple of the binary data.

How can I iterate over all the elements in the tuple and use `struct.unpack` to recreate the list of floats?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate your tuple to get a unique string with your raw data, and then use unpack on it.

Let's say you have (Python 2 here):

```
t = ('\x00','\x00','\x80','?')
struct.unpack("f", "".join(t))
```

Would give me the required answer `(1,)`

Python3 should be:

```
t = (b'\x00',b'\x00',b'\x80',b'?')
struct.unpack("f", b"".join(t))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Would you mind showing me how?

Comment: Added an example.